# How add certificate for auth to repository

Tags: artifactory

For install nginx-plus package I should add certificate (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-plus/#installing-nginx-plus-on-debian-and-ubuntu). I want create mirror repository, but I don't understand where I should add certificate for auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configuring the [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories) in Artifactory which will be used to [proxy](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Debian+Repositories#DebianRepositories-RemoteRepositories) the NginX Debian repository, you can add the SSL certificate in the [Advanced Settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings) tab. Inside the Remote Authentication section you will find a field for setting the SSL/TLS certificate this repository should use for authentication to the remote resource for which it is a proxy.